# Delay on start-up load content page

Tags: google-chrome, delay, pageload

In page load start-up Google Chrome show me just page layout (like blew image) and after one second inject content like text and font-icon and etc.In your opinion, this problem related to my html, css or js? or Do you have any suggestion to resolve this problem?

[image: chrome load page on stratup]

Comment: It might be google just loading your page. But for us to be able to help you you need to share your code.

Comment: I am using laravel as backend and use jquery and bootstrap as front-end. I have multiple js and css that load in startup, but in Firefox I don't see this problem